# What determines Checkpoints?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

In Diablo 3 Ultimate Evil Editon, I am having a very rough time figuring out how to tell someone that they do not need to blow an entire Act just to stop playing.  My problem is this, I have the ability to half way in a map, press XBOX and leave the game.  For my friend it doesnt seem to work the same way for what ever reason.  Her gear and skill progression reset to what last was and exp does not.  Since I do know the game stays the same at a check point, what determines when a check point occurs and can I set those off at any given time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the mechanic works (essentially) same way as it does on PC. Checkpoints are fairly obvious:

[image]

As for the "autosave" features, the main thing to remember is that they are triggered at regular intervals, but unlike games like Skyrim or Fallout for example, specific save points cannot be accessed by the player.

So essentially, if you quit to dashboard at any time during the game, you are bypassing the autosave feature, and you *will* lose any kind of progress after the last autosave.

Comment: So how do I not bypass it

Comment: Quit to menu, then exit from there. That will force an autosave.